# Laravel + Passport + Vue - Não encontrando

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Senhores, estou começando a desenvolver uma aplicação utilizando o método Passport do Laravel, mas não esta encontrando a biblioteca VUE. segue uma imagem com o retorno do navegador: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

arquivo js que faz a importação da biblioteca VUE
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

arquivo blade que faz a leitura 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde posso estar errando?

Obrigado

Comment: Copie e cole o trecho do código, evite postar código como imagem, fica difícil de copiar e colar em um ambiente adequado pra reproduzir o seu problema =]

Comment: =) Obrigado, vou postar!

Comment: Tenta rodar `npm run dev`